# LuaLaTeX complains about \pdfinclusioncopyfonts

Tags: luatex

When I try to use LuaLaTeX to build a simple document as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

I got the following error complaining `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts`

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01>
(using write cache: /home/hong/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(usi
ng read cache: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic /home/hong/.texlive2016/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.081 seconds
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo(compiling luc: /var/li
b/texmf/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc)(load luc: /home/h
ong/.texlive2016/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc
)))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \pdfinclusioncopyfonts
                        =1
```

But PDFLaTeX can successfully build the document. Looks like LuaLaTeX is supposed to support that option. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before `\documentclass` should solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from version 0.95, LuaTeX has removed `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts` changing it into

```
\pdfvariable inclusioncopyfonts
```

so the correct syntax would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\pdfvariable inclusioncopyfonts=1

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

However, there's the package `luatex85` that comes to the rescue in this and several other cases where LuaTeX did similar changes:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}

\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

It's a good idea to add the top line to every file you plan to compile with LuaLaTeX. The `luatex85` package will do nothing if the current engine is not LuaTeX version 0.95 or later.

Comment: Note that `luatex85` is meant to allow an easy transition here _but_ the expectation is that LuaTeX-dependent documents will be updated to use the new primitives

Comment: @JosephWright I'd be happier if the LaTeX kernel provides some interface, such as `\setpdfvariable{inclusioncopyfonts}{1}`, which could be made engine independent.

Comment: @egreg LaTeX3 is just around the corner, right? :P